# Failed to load Glass factory class : Keep on Getting this error for Linux and some mac os machine but works fine otherwise

Tags: java, fxml, openjfx

I made a Jar file on Intellij, and I was able to make it run in Windows and some MacOS but not otherwise (so some MacOS and Linux wont work)

What i have done :

1. Change the `javafx` version from 17 to 11.
2. Added the `module-info.java` and add java controls and fxml
   Context this is my `build.gradle` file

```
plugins {
    id 'checkstyle'
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '7.1.2'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.13'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version: '5.10.0'
    testRuntimeOnly group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-engine', version: '5.10.0'

    String javaFxVersion = '17.0.8'

    implementation group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-base', version: javaFxVersion, classifier: 'win'
    implementation group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-base', version: javaFxVersion, classifier: 'mac'
    implementation group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-base', version: javaFxVersion, classifier: 'linux'
    implementation group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-controls', version: javaFxVersion, classifier: 'win'
    implementation group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-controls', version: javaFxVersion, classifier: 'mac'
    implementation group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-controls', version: javaFxVersion, classifier: 'linux'
    implementation group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-fxml', version: javaFxVersion, classifier: 'win'
    implementation group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-fxml', version: javaFxVersion, classifier: 'mac'
    implementation group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-fxml', version: javaFxVersion, classifier: 'linux'
    implementation group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-graphics', version: javaFxVersion, classifier: 'win'
    implementation group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-graphics', version: javaFxVersion, classifier: 'mac'
    implementation group: 'org.openjfx', name: 'javafx-graphics', version: javaFxVersion, classifier: 'linux'

}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()

    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"

        showExceptions true
        exceptionFormat "full"
        showCauses true
        showStackTraces true
        showStandardStreams = false
    }
}

javafx {
    version = '17'
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
}

application {
    mainClass.set("seedu.Launcher")
}

shadowJar {
    archiveBaseName = "duke"
    archiveClassifier = null
    dependsOn("distZip", "distTar")
}

checkstyle {
    toolVersion = '10.2'
}

run {
    standardInput = System.in
}
```

Java version i am using is 11

```
Sep 16, 2023 12:08:25 AM com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl startup
WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @6712f432'
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkPlatformFactory
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.PlatformFactory.getPlatformFactory(PlatformFactory.java:42)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:146)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:291)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:293)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:163)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:659)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:679)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Failed to load Glass factory class
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:146)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:291)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:293)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:163)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:659)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:679)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem from https://github.com/nus-cs2103-AY2223S1/forum/issues/213#issuecomment-1249046920

> I also get the same error in Linux (Arch). For fixing the issue: remove the javafx {} block at the end of build.gradle. That part is actually restricting the packages.

Comment: When quoting something, please include where you found it. See [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)

Comment: I will fix the plagiarism this time. Please do it yourself next time.